# How can I define an class' array while constructing it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If you declare an array, you have to assign its elements (or at least acknowledge that it is an array) while declaring it, i.e., `var myArray = [1, 2, 3];`.

I'm curious as to how one might be able to implement that in an class constructor, for example:

```
function Matrix(MultiDimensionalArray) {
    this.array = MultiDimensionalArray;
}
var myMatrix = new Matrix() [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
```

That's the closest thing I could think of to implement this, but I know that it's incorrect. What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: You are missing commas(`,`) after every item. Second, your nested array should be passed between parenthesis. Also, functions are declared as `function functionMName(argumentList) { function body}`

Comment: Put the array inside your parenthesis.

Comment: var myMatrix = new Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor call  would be like this:

```
 var myMatrix = new Matrix([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])
```

Comment: It is not a constructor but a constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

There are many syntactical mistakes in your code.

1. Function declaration

You can declare functions like:

```
function functionName(argList) {}
```

or

```
var functionName = function(argList){}
```

2. Passing arguments

You have to put arguments within parenthesis. So it should be `Matrix([...])`

3. Array declaration

Items in an array are separated using commas. You will have to do `[ [], [], [] ]`.

4. variable names

In the following code:

```
function Matrix = (MultiDimensionalArray) {
    this.array = multiDimensionalArray;
```

variable accepted and variable assigned are different. You will have to use the same values.

**Sample Code:**

```js
function Matrix(multiDimensionalArray) {
    this.array = multiDimensionalArray;
}
var myMatrix = new Matrix([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]);

console.log(myMatrix.array)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myMatrix = new Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]);
```

Comment: This should have been a comment. You are also missing explanation.

Comment: I have also commented with an explanation @Rajesh. Please check my comment on his question. Infact I answered after commenting.

Comment: Also, the answer above me was also the same. I really don't understand this bias.

Comment: @VinodBhavnani I voted your comment as it was correct. But there is a difference between answer and a comment. Also about bias, no one here is anyone's enemy. Your answer looks more like a comment and will attract unwanted voted.

Comment: "Put the array inside your parenthesis." is a comment. A piece of code showing how to do it, is an answer. I think I am pretty sure I know what a comment and an answer is. Anyways, if you go around downvoting people because you think something is a comment, while it is an answer, you are actually misinterpreted. A piece of code showing how to do it, cannot be a comment. Period!